# How to Update a Finite-Width Cellular Automaton

Tags: cellular-automata

How does one instruct `CellularAutomaton` to wrap at the edges?  (I want a 2d finite-width CA, so it evolves on a torus.)  I cannot tell from the docs if this is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From some experiments and from reading between the lines of the documentation, if the second argument is a vector, then the system set up with periodic boundary conditions. See for example this one:

```
ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[30, PadLeft[{1}, 100], 150]]
```

[image]

Comment: If you can elaborate a bit more on which documentation you are relying on and how it applies to the 2D (instead of 1d) case, that would help.  I am guessing you are referring to this: "a_1,a_2,... explicit list of values a_i, assumed cyclic".  I suppose that is suppose to mean that this `init` is implicitly 1d wrapping at the bounderies).  In which case, I suppose, a 2d rectangular array for `init` should implicitly be 2d wrapping at the boundaries.

Comment: Yes, exactly there. I only found it by searching for "cyclic" and "periodic" (with ctrl + f). I am not sure, but the 2D case should work exactly as you have just anticipated.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way to specify the initial condition:

```
ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[30, SparseArray[1 -> 1, 50], 50]]
```

[image]

**Note:** [CellularAutomaton >> Scope >> Initial Conditions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellularAutomaton.html):

> *Explicit initial conditions are assumed cyclic*